# flutter ClipRect has no borderRadius property

Tags: flutter, dart

Every example of ClipRect has it followed by the borderRadius property.   This for some reason does not exist for me:

[image: compiler]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can see here as well it does not autosuggest any properties when you start typing "a" or "b" and the first properties that get suggested start with "c":

[image: nothing for b]

[image: something for c]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `ClipRRect` which has `borderRadius` property.